# Внезапно перестали загружаться иксы в Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Внезапно перестали загружаться иксы в Linux Mint 17.1 (32-bit).
Просто вылазит черный экран с окном сообщения:

"Cinnamon just crashed! You are currently running fallback mode?"

И диалог, мол "Да/Нет". Нажав "Да", все повторяется по-новой, "Нет" - просто висит черный экран и не реагирует ни на что...

Comment: А что в syslog?

Comment: В syslog после этого 300 kb информации. Что конкретно там смотреть, я не понимаю....

Comment: tail /var/log/syslog

Comment: Ну, да.... Там было полутора МБ. Удалил и попробовал войти в иксы. Не вышло. Зашел под пользователем. Итог - 300 kb лога.

Comment: Ну так последние строки хотя бы выложи.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько приемлемых вариантов решения:

1. Обновить ОС Linux Mint
2. Обновить\переустановить Cinnamon т.к в 17.1 не самый последний релиз, возможно в новой версии ваша ошибка уже исправлена разработчиками.
3. Переустановить драйверы для видео-карты, т.к согласно гуглу есть пользовали которым это решение помогало.
4. Удалить и установить заново xorg